# How does breeze js cache know if a sub entity was changed?

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze, single-page-application

Given the following 1 to Many data structure:

Personnel <- Phones

And I pulled Personnel first, and on a separate call I retrieve Phone.

So now there're 2 references to the same Phone, one that's under Personnel and another that's a stand alone. Are they copies or references? Does the manager know to resolve this?

If it does, what kind of convention does it need to reconcile the 2 entities in the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an EntityManager, Breeze caches all entities by their keys, so you will never have duplicates of the same entity. Breeze also fixes up any references for children or parents that are queried independently ( this depends on having correct metadata about the foreign key property of the dependent objects), so regardless of how you queried the phones there will only ever be one instance of each phone and that instance will be automatically hooked up to its parent 'Personnel' entity.

Comment: Jay, Can you give me pointer what convention breeze uses to differentiate fk vs. pk vs. regular properties?

Comment: This is all described by metadata. Discussion of the topic is found here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata